# Getting Location Services Running Unity/Tango

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, location, tango

I am building a simple app in Unity/Tango platform.

I am trying to get the location. 
I followed the steps in this https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LocationService.Start.html

So after 20 seconds wait it 'Timed out' and the Status is always 'initializing'.
The Input.location.lastData.latitude and Input.location.lastData.longitude is always zero.

In addition I have set this in the AndroidManifest.xml file:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="true" />`

Any help would be appreciated.

-Thanks

Comment: What device do you use? Do you try other app (location)? It work?

Comment: I am using Tango (Android 4.4 KitKat). I have enabled the location services in the device. Not sure what other app you are referring to?

Comment: for example, google map work?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:
On Android devices, LocationService doesn’t work without setting “high accuracy” location mode in the system settings (“Settings” -> “Location” -> “Mode”).

Reference:
https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/android-locationservice-doesnt-work-without-high-accuracy-mode